# Naming Terminology of REST and gRPC in API Design

Tags: rest, grpc, terminology

REST is known as an architectural style for API design while gRPC follows the RPC style. This implies we cannot put gRPC into "an architectural style" category due to the fact that it is an application of the RPC style. So, concerning API design, do you think we can call REST and gRPC as "two variations of API design techniques" instead of emphasizing the word "style" in case we want to compare them in the same terminology context in an academic text? Thanks.

Comment: If you are looking for a specific application of REST, some examples include JSON:API and ODATA.

Comment: I don't think you can outright compare REST to gRPC, without thoroughly listing your assumptions for what REST means. Most people using the term 'REST" are far removed from the REST dissertation from Roy Fielding. If you are not doing hypermedia, you're not really doing REST, yet when most people compare gRPC to REST, they are not using hypermedia.

Comment: What's your definition?

Comment: To be precise, my aim is to validate if the following statement would sound acceptable in an academic paper:  "In the software industry, there are API design techniques, such as Representational State Transfer (REST), Google’s Remote Procedure Call framework (gRPC), and Apache Thrift that can be utilized in the design and development of server-side applications' API ". Would you think this statement sound normal/acceptable?

Comment: I think they are all techniques that can be used for APIs so it's not wrong. If you would ask me, are they all in the same 'category' of things, then REST is the odd one out.

Comment: I'd even argue that `gRPC` and `Apache Thrift` are two frameworks or libraries why REST is not. [gRPC](https://grpc.io/) even claims that it is a `modern open source high performance Remote Procedure Call (RPC) framework` as does [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) whitch defines itself as `software framework, for scalable cross-language services development` to generate RPC stub-classes that can be used both by clients and servers. If you will, REST is a collection of constraints that when adhered to helps in decoupling clients from servers, so the opposite of what RPC does